# How to use Google Analytics API

Tags: asp.net-core, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Does anyone know how to get site or application statistics from Google Analytics and display them in an ASP core 5  project as a chart?

I would appreciate it if you answer my question

The codes provided by Google give errors for new client login.

This link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples

Answer (score 0):

The code and link you mentioned is related to the old version which has been expired on July 2023. Please migrate to Google Analytics 4 which is
The related code and info can be found[Google Analytics Data API (GA4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries).

Comment: I tested the sample codes, but these have also expired

Comment: It is not possible, that is the latest API, I am using everyday. share exact error you get please.

Comment: I tried to test the below link codes but the following package is not available in nuget
https://github.com/googleanalytics/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/26d740abc60e040501c08ee7932c0c803a889fa6/analytics-data
package: Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta

Comment: I work with C# and ASP.NET Core

Comment: @Sahar for the C# or other languages you may find unofficial libraries. That is not so hard to use Java for example. You only need to read the info and save into your DB.